# Angular Js- Bootstrap table not refreshing immediately after new data is added

Tags: angularjs

books.html

```
<div ng-controller="BookController">
        <table datatable="ng" class="row-border hover" ng-table="tableParams">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>BookID</th>
                    <th>BookName</th>
                    <th>Author</th>
                    <th>ISBNCode</th>
                    <th>NoOfBooks</th>
                    <th>PublishDate</th>
                    <th>NoOfBooksIssued</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="book in books">
                    <td>{{book.BookId}}</td>
                    <td>{{book.BookName}}</td>
                    <td>{{book.Author}}</td>
                    <td>{{book.ISBNCode}}</td>
                    <td>{{book.NoOfBooks}}</td>
                    <td>{{book.PublishDate}}</td>
                    <td>{{book.NoOfBooksIssued}}</td>
                    <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></p></td>
                    <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></p></td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Bookcontroller.js

```
"use strict";
(function () {
    angular.module("Bookapp")
        .controller("BookController", ["$scope", "BookService",
        function ($scope, bookService) {
            bookService.getRequest()
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.books = JSON.parse(response);
                });
        }]);
})();



AddBookController.js

"use strict";
(function () {
    angular.module('Bookapp')
        .controller('AddBookController', ["$scope", "BookService",
        function ($scope, bookService) {
            $scope.save = function (item) {
                bookService.postRequest(item)
                    .then(function () {
                        location.path("books");
                });
            }
        }]);
})();
```

Both the js files are 2 different custom files which are included in the master page. I have also written BookService.js. Which is as follows:

```
"use strict";
    (function () {
        angular.module("Bookapp")
            .factory("BookService", ["$http", "$q", function ($http, $q) {
                var baseURL = "http://localhost:27136/api/book";
                var getRequest = function (query) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    $http({
                        url: baseURL,
                        method: "GET"
                    })
                        .success(function (result) {
                            deferred.resolve(result);
                        })
                        .error(function (result, status) {
                            deferred.reject(status);
                        });
                    return deferred.promise;
                };
                var getByIdRequest = function (id) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    $http({
                        url: baseURL + "/" + id,
                        method: "GET"
                    })
                        .success(function (result) {
                            deferred.resolve(result);
                        })
                        .error(function (result, status) {
                            deferred.reject(status);
                        });
                    return deferred.promise;
                };
                var postRequest = function (data) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    $http({
                        url: baseURL,
                        method: "POST",
                        data: JSON.stringify(data)
                    })
                        .success(function (result) {
                            deferred.resolve(result);
                        })
                        .error(function (result, status) {
                            deferred.reject(status);
                        });
                    return deferred.promise;
                };
                var updateRequest = function (data, id) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    $http({
                        url: baseURL + "/" + id,
                        method: "PUT",
                        data: JSON.stringify(data)
                    })
                        .success(function (result) {
                            deferred.resolve(result);
                        })
                        .error(function (result, status) {
                            deferred.reject(status);
                        });
                    return deferred.promise;
                };
                var deleteRequest = function (id) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    $http({
                        url: baseURL + "/" + id,
                        method: "DELETE"
                    })
                        .success(function (result) {
                            deferred.resolve(result);
                        })
                        .error(function (result, status) {
                            deferred.reject(status);
                        });
                    return deferred.promise;
                };
                return {
                    getRequest: getRequest,
                    getByIdRequest: getByIdRequest,
                    postRequest: postRequest,
                    updateRequest: updateRequest,
                    deleteRequest: deleteRequest
                };
            }]);
    })()
```

My problem is when I click on the add button below my table the details of the book that i have entered must update in the table immediately which is not happening in my case. I have 2 different controllers one is BookController which will get all the books details from db using a service method and display in the table. The other one is AddBookController which will add the new book details to the table.In AddBookController itself i have written code to get the data after posting it to db. But i am not able to refresh the table with new data.Please help me. Thank you so Much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have a code smell in your service because you don't need to use $q service for retrieving a promise from $http.

$http always return a promise itself!

so you can simplify all your functions like this:

```
var getRequest = function (query) {
    return $http({
        url: baseURL,
        method: "GET"
    });
};
```

For your question

Have you try debugging the `bookService.getRequest()` request?

Try putting a console.log in your book controller and see if it's called after the add.

Maybe you need to trigger the get request after the add.

Comment: bookService.getRequest() is working fine @eliagentili. And I have placed a console.log() after the add and I am able to see the book details i just added in the console after i click on add button. Please check below for modified AddBookController.js file. Thanks In Advance

Comment: Even after i changed the code as follows, the table is not getting refreshed immediately

Answer (score 0):

```
"use strict";
(function () {
    angular.module('Bookapp')
        .controller('AddBookController', ["$scope", "BookService",
        function ($scope, bookService) {
            $scope.save = function (item) {
                console.log(item);
                bookService.postRequest(item)
                    .then(function () {
                        bookService.getRequest()
                        .then(function (response) {
                            $scope.books = JSON.parse(response);
                        });
                });
            }
        }]);
})();
```